# java card applet convert error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, converters, javacard

I am new to java card development.when i try to convert java applet in to cap file it will give this error in eclipse.what is the reason??
(My **eclipse is version 3.7.2** and **java 1.7** and java card sdk **2.2.2** )

**Java Card 2.2.2 Class File Converter, Version 1.3
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
error: hms.transport.javacard.HelloWorld: unsupported class file format of version 51.0.
error: hms.transport.javacard.HelloWorldRI: unsupported class file format of version 51.0.
error: hms.transport.javacard.HelloWorldRIImpl: unsupported class file format of version 51.0.
error: hms.transport.javacard.HelloWorldSI: unsupported class file format of version 51.0.
error: hms.transport.javacard.HelloWorldSIImpl: unsupported class file format of version 51.0.
conversion completed with 5 errors and 0 warnings.**

Comment: I hope this is a typo, you can not convert "Java Applets" for JavaCard, only "Java Card applets" can be converted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message "class file format of version 51.0" means that the class files you want to convert has been generated for Java 1.7 which is not supported.

If you are compiling your Java files with Eclipse you have to change the "Java Compiler" in the project settings. Enable project specific settings and change the compliance level to Java 1.5.